# Finding a period with the least NA:s in multiple time series

Tags: python, time-series, nan

I have approximately 20 000 time series during a 5-year period. In that period I would like to find a 18-month period which contains as little NA:s as possible. What is the most efficient way of doing this in Python?

See attached example for structure of dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
```

#### Load the dataset and print the 5 top rows

df = pd.read_excel('so.xlsx', index_col = 'Date')

[Dataframe Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzQS5.png)

Comment: could you please include the actual data (not as picture) in the question, so others can try to reproduce your question / challenge / problem?

Comment: Also - to make sure I understand correctly - since you have a row for each months, looking for the least NaN is the same as looking for the most values, right?

Comment: I am not sure python has specific tools for this. I fear you might just need to analyze each time series with a 'window' of 18 months, and determine when this has the most data/least NAs

Comment: Unfortunately I cant upload the data since it is non-disclosure. To your second question, yes! :)

Comment: We do not need *real* data. What we need is just enough data (fake data is no problem) and/or code to reproduce. If you do not provide that, you expect each person willing to answer to build its own fake data. And as long as I am concerned, if OP does not prove a minimum effort by providing data, I am more than reluctant to answer... Providing (possibly fake) data is just a way to attract more (better?) answers...

Comment: Hint (not answer with code because no data to test against ;-) ): looks like a use case for `rolling` + `sum`.

Comment: ok thanks for clarifying, since I am new at SO  I did not know that. I added the code snippet but I see no way of attaching the excel file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution (using fake data with randomly located NaN):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": np.random.choice(list(np.arange(3)) + [np.NaN], len(time_range)), 
              "b": np.random.choice(list(np.arange(3)) + [np.NaN], len(time_range)), 
              "c": np.random.choice(list(np.arange(3)) + [np.NaN], len(time_range)), 
              "d": np.random.choice(list(np.arange(3)) + [np.NaN], len(time_range))}, 
             index=time_range)

# count the number of nan in any given 18-months period 
df["18_month_na"] = df.isna().sum(axis=1).rolling(18).sum()

# get the minimum.     
df.loc[df["18_month_na"].idxmin()]
```

Comment: it was just because I ran the '# count the number of nan in any given 18-months period' code snippet twice that this occured, as it includes the values from the new column in the second run. Thanks again!